# pass two values in ng-repeat and ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

Controller:

```
var response = {
  "json": {
    "response": {
      "servicetype": "100",
      "functiontype": "101",
      "statuscode": "success",
      "data": [
        {
          "countryid": 1,
          "countryname": "India",
          "countrycode": "91",
          "currencyname": "Indian rupee",
          "currencycode": "INR",
          "latitude": "21.7679",
          "longitude": "78.8718"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

  $scope.country = response.json.response.data;
```

Html:

```
 <select name="Country" class="form-control1 drop countries" required  ng-model="model.country" placeholder="Select" value="India"  ng-change="getState(model.country);">
    <option value="" disabled selected> Country*</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in country track by $index" value="{{item.countryid}}">{{item.countryname}}</option>
        </select>
```

I wanted to pass both the countryname and countryid to fetch list of states , need solution . I could just pass only country id. Need assistance.

Comment: So you're looking to pass two things into the ng-change? Won't this work: ng-change="getState(model.country, model.id)" ?

Comment: what about model.id ? how we assign it

Comment: Mistake on that last one. Ok, so getState() is a method on your controller right? model.country is passed in, should be the model you've selected in the dropdown, so getState() should have everything it needs if you want countryname/countryid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="country" required
    ng-options="c as c.countryname for c in country track by c.countryid" ng-change="getState(country.countryid, country.countryname);" >
    <option value="">Country*</option>
</select>
```

Use `ng-options`, you will get all values in country model

Comment: ng-change doesnt work for me. getState(item.id,item.country) I get undefined values.

Comment: can you just pass getState(country)

Comment: Pls check ur model name, if it is country change to `item'

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` instead:

```
 <select  ng-model="model.country" required
    ng-options="c.countryid as c.countryname for c in country" >
    <option value="">Country*</option>
</select>
```

It will give you output:

```
<select ng-model="model.country" required="" 
       ng-options="c.countryid as c.countryname for c in country" 
       class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    <option value="" class="">Country*</option>
    <option value="0">India</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>[Demo Fillde](http://jsfiddle.net/q058bnmc/)</kbd>

---

About your case: `track by $index` is what breaks your `select`

<kbd>[Demo Fillde 2](http://jsfiddle.net/yn8qrbg1/)</kbd>

Comment: But my question is about ng-change and its missing in your answer. Could you assist me in passing countryid and countryname